# pygame on mac does not close nor register keys

Tags: python, pygame

I am having a problem with pygame on mac. It wont close when clicking on the 'x' button. It also would not move the space ship at all with the arrow keys. Any suggestions?

```
while running:
    screen.fill((255,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -0.1
        if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0.1
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change=0
        

playerX+=playerX_change

player(playerX, playerY)
pygame.display.update()
```

[image: Actual code]

Comment: update...i was able to get the space ship to move by correcting a line in the code. instead of "event.key", i typed in 'event.type'. Once i corrected that, the ship started to move. However, i am still having issues with closing the game...let me know if anyone figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your code is not complete for me, but i have an idea that was occurr.

```
while running:
    screen.fill((255,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -0.1
            playerX+=playerX_change

        if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0.1
            playerX+=playerX_change

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change=0
 

player(playerX, playerY)
pygame.display.update()
```

Maybe if you transfer to position that change the respective position directly works fine

> playerX+=playerX_change

Comment: Not only does the spaceship not move but the screen would not close when pressing "x". could this be an issue with the setup/download of pygame instead of the code itself?

Comment: from pygame.locals import *

Answer (score 0):

I think the last three lines of code should be within the while loop. Without doing so, your display does not update with each iteration.

Comment: Thanks but the last three lines are in the whole loop.

Comment: @jara sorry, but when I posted they weren't. The image was not there and if you copy-paste the code, you'll see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The events need to be evaluated in the event loop:

```py
while running:
    screen.fill((255,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # INDENTATION
    #-->|
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.1
            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change=0
            

    playerX+=playerX_change

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks but all the codes are indented as they should. Just clarify, the codes were copied from a youtube video and it worked on the video. When i run the codes on my mac, it will not close pygame nor move the ships when clicking on the arrows.